# Issues with input dimension in a simple tensorflow model

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have issues with making prediction with a custom trained model.

It inputs 128 dimensions vector and output two values.

So far my model looks like this:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 128)               16512
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 258
=================================================================
Total params: 16,770
Trainable params: 16,770
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Thus I try to input data to make a prediciton, (for the example purpose its only a np.ones array)

```
my_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_saved_model.h5')


probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([my_model, tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])


simple_data = np.ones((128))

predictions = probability_model.predict(simple_data)
print(predictions)
```

And output an error about the shape of the simple_data being as (32, 1) :

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 128 but received input with shape (32, 1)
```

I have no idea why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try to add the batch dimension in your input data, something like this:

```
simple_data = np.ones((1, 128))
```

And I think you must add the arg `batch_size=1` in the predict method.